# How to read attribute of shaperead output in matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I extract one of the attribute form shaperead in matlab
Here is example for a file available in matlab.

```
S = shaperead('concord_hydro_line.shp')
```

The output of this is
[image]

I want to extract the 'LENGTH' array from the output.
Doing "S.LENGTH" only returns one value. I want the whole array. How can I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you get from `S.LENGTH` is a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) of the 237 values in the `LENGTH` field. If you assign that to a single variable: `out = S.LENGTH;` only the *first* value from the list is actually assigned.

To assign *all* values, use `[s.LENGTH]`
or `{s.LENGTH}` to respectively convert the list to a standard array or to a cell array, which you can then assign to a variable: `out = [s.LENGTH];` or `out = {s.LENGTH};`. The former only works if the contents of the `LENGTH` field have matching sizes.